# How can you use &nbsp; or <nobr> from within the Wordpress Classic Blocks (page editor)

Tags: html, wordpress, nobr

I am using the following: WordPress Version: 5.5 / PHP Version: 7.4.3 / XAMPP Version: 7.4.3 / Bootstrap Version: 3.3

I need to have a section of text on a page to not break.

I have used the view source option from the toolbar, and have manually inserted the no breaking options ( like: &n b s p; or < nobr >< /nobr > - I've added spacing to allow me to have the html code shown here).

I have also tried using the **insert** 'nonbreaking space' option from the toolbar.

But once I save or 'publish' the page, and view via the client website (using inspect), the non-breaking code I wanted added is not there.

Is there any way to do this within the edit page option in wordpress, using Classic Blocks or otherwise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `&nbsp;` to regular paragraph blocks when editing as HTML and they will be preserved when publishing.

[image: screenshot]